# Inflating AppCompat Theme programmatically

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using the google design support library for Android. I want to have a RelativeLayout which inside it has a FloatingActionButton. The problem is that I am inflating the view using:

```
mLayoutInflater.inflate(window.getLayoutResource(), null)
```

I get an exception thrown that tells me that the parent has to use the AppCompat theme for the design library.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

What can I do to inflate layouts that don't have activity's that have themes attached to them?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to specify a theme to the highest layout inside the XML that uses AppCompat.

I.E:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ....
```

Then all the elements under it will inflate normally using

```
mLayoutInflater.inflate(window.getLayoutResource(), null)
```